# Determine $h$ so that the linear system $Ax=b$ has infinitely many solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing some repetition and I got stuck on this question:

**Determine $h$ so that the linear system $Ax=b$ has infinitely many solutions.**

$$ A =\begin{pmatrix}
  5 & 3 & 2 \\
  -7 & -1 & 6 \\
  -6 & 6 & h
 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$b= \begin{pmatrix}
  6 \\ 1 \\ 21
 \end{pmatrix}$$

This is supposed to be an easy question, and I think you should be able to "see" directly what the solution might be. I find that hard to do since none of the columns or rows of $A$ are an obvious multiple of another. How would you approach solving this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum of row 1 and row 2 multiplied by 3 is $(-6\ 6\ 24)$, hence $h=24$.

Comment: Thank you! This was probably how the question was intended to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Obtain the solutions for the truncated system
$$\pmatrix{5&3&2\\-7&-1&6} x = \pmatrix{6\\1}$$
Now find out wich $h$ satisfies $\pmatrix{-6&6&h}x = 21$ for all solutions to the above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AlexR if you have time I would love to see how you would solve the calculations that you described.

Comment: @LukasArvidsson I think you should do that yourself, I recommend chosing $x_3$ as a free variable in the first system so you get
$$x_1 = a + bx_3, x_2 = c+dx_3$$ and then plug these into the equation $-6x_1 + 6x_2 + hx_3 = 21$ to see what value of $h$ will lead to a $0=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I will definitely look into this, although I think it should be possible to solve this question more intuitively.